# Which type of function is ReL?

Tags: backpropagation, relu

I was wondering if the ReL function is a linear or an identity function.

If the function was linear (meaning y=kx+d) the function could be "changed" a lot more.

If the function on the other hand was an identity function (meaning y=x), then output wouldn't be changed - at least for positive inputs.

As far as I've read, positive values that are ran through a ReLU are not changed. Meaning, that the function (from 0 onwards) is an identity function. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

When it's applied on a set of input values evenly distributed around zero, the ReL function is linear for half of the input domain (on the positive input values) and nonlinear for the other half. Thus, it is referred to as a piecewise linear function or a hinge function.

Comment: Meaning that the Input doesn't get changed, therefore the function is y=x. Correct?

Comment: @Phil3453 but not for the whole function.